# python console does not display ü

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

dear fellow developers,

I have tried to teach python console to display ü, but it insists with displaying Ã¼ instead. I have tried it with Python 3.5 and Python 3.6. The result is the same. If I run a .py file containing line print("ü") with F5 command, it displays

```
Ã¼
```

instead of ü. If I type in the console

```
print ("ü")
```

it displays

```
ü
```

I know it has been discussed many times, but most of the methods I have come across during the last 5 hours have not helped me or I have not applied them properly. The problem exists also with other non ascii characters. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Presumably you're using IDLE? What's your operating system version? These details matter.

Comment: I tried it both with IDLE and Spyder. but the result was the same. but the problem was with file encoding. since in this file I attached also another file, I added encoding='utf-8' to the open command. And made sure both files had utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line on the top on your source file : `# coding: utf-8`

Also, check if your file encoding is correct (Always choose UTF-8).

Comment: Note that IDLE actually changes the source encoding when you add this line, so there’s a potential for something surprising to happen.

Comment: thanks! The utf8 comment I had on the top. But my file encoding was indeed something else. Changing the encoding to utf8 finally did the trick.